# Wrangling lists with possible empty values in output

Tags: terraform

We refactored some code, and when it was written an array was guaranteed to have 4 elements.  Now it can have 4 or 0.  The output statement from the module was: (stripped down a bit for simplicity)

```
output "foo" {
 value = { "valuea" = thing.subthing[0].id,
           "valueb" = thing.subthing[1].id,
           "valuec" = thing.subthing[2].id,
           "valued" = thing.subthing[3].id
}
```

Now when thing.subthing is an empty tuple, it understandbly blows chunks.  I'm drawing a blank on the most straightforward way to determine that it's empty, and move on.

These are actually a list of subnets ids, which because a flag got added to skip their creation, never got made because their count was set to 0.  I've got about 12 more things in that file I'll fix exactly the same way...

Oh, tf 0.12.20something btw.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting stuck on the usual tricks, like concatting with a an empty array still blew chunks on the missing tuple, until I was reminded that the splat notation worked differently, so

`length(thing.subthing[*].id) > 0 ? thing.subthing[0].id : 0

Works fine.

Although now I think of it, that's left over from our 0.11 code, I should probably refactor value into an array convert this into for_each code.  In my copious spare time.